# Is there any way to keyframe specific points with AnimAll?

Tags: animation, add-on

I've recently discovered an included plugin called *AnimAll* which allows you to animate... Pretty much anything, including UV mappings.

But I've noticed that it keyframes every single possible node/point that's possible (ie. for UV maps), as opposed to just the selected vertexes which armature and pretty much nearly everything in the properties tabs allows keyframing for.

For example, in the picture below, *every single* UV point has a keyframe on that model, and not just the eyes.

[image: Notice that really long list of channels for each property (UV point).]

## Is it possible to limit keyframing to specific vertexes, just like object keys?

While deleting keys is a practical solution to remove the amount of calculations that need to be calculated (less keys = less changes, even if those changes are literally 'no change at all') there is no feasible way to identify which vertex belongs to which set of keys.

Comment: You can always delete the ones you don't need afterward.

Comment: Also, any channels that are locked will not accept new keyframe data. So in your case locking may be a solution.

Comment: @Mentalist The problem with that is that it's impossible to work out which point is which without lots of experimenting. And boy will that take forever to work out which channels is for which point on the UV Maps